# How to Turn On a Wall Heater

Tags: heating, gas, natural-gas, pilot-light, gas-burner

There is this wall heater in my new apartment.

This is the inside the panel. There is a hole in the middle. The bottom has a knob that only has "off"  "high" and "low" modes. 
[image]

[image][image][image]

I cannot find anything that says pilot light, or anywhere to light a pilot light flame.

Help. It's 40F inside and bloody cold here. Thanks.

Comment: In the second picture, the smaller tube that starts just below the flame observation hole and snakes off to the right.  Where does it go?  That appears to be the tube for gas delivery to the pilot.  Where does it snake off to on the right?  Where it connects there should be an override button to get the pilot flame started.  It may also be part of the main control, does that large press in, most likely only when rotated to one position?

Answer (score 2):

Check the valve in the bottom 2 pictures that is connected to the pipe that comes up through the floor. That is the manual gas valve that may need to be turned if it is turned off. First, turn the knob marked off, low and high to OFF. Then, in the bottom 2 pictures, that RED knob or button that slants to the left and slightly downward will need to be pushed in to allow the gas to flow to the pilot. While pushing that stem in, stick a match into the hole to light the pilot. Hold the red stem in for a minute or 2. When you release that red stem the pilot should stay on, if not , redo the last step. Once the pilot stays lit you can turn that handle set to off to low or high and gas should flow. If it doesn't work you may need to call a service co. for help. Let us know if you get heat.

Comment: Once I get the pilot to light by pushing the red button I would continue holding the pilot button and turn the gas on if the burner lights it will usually continue running even after a few seconds but I maintain the pilot for 30 seconds and let go.+

Answer (score 1):

This is an Empire style wall furnace.  It does not need electricity.  *You'll be glad for that later*.

The twisty valve is designed to completely shut off gas flow if it doesn't feel heat from the pilot light.  This is a safety feature designed to keep your apartment from filling with gas and exploding.  You will find this kind of safety feature on many piloted gas appliances, such as water heaters.

How do you get the pilot lit in the first place? You push and hold down the red button, which tells the valve "flow pilot light gas *anyway* so I can get the pilot lit and the sensor warmed up."   This warmup *takes as long as it takes*, longer obviously if it is colder.

Then you set the switch to off (w/ pilot), low or high.

I don't see any wiring to support it, it may not be in view.  But typically an Empire style furnace will have a Real, Actual Thermostat somewhere on a wall. This is powered by a loop circuit: from a *thermocouple* near the pilot light making electric current from its heat, to the millivolt thermostat which turns on electricity (or not), to the *solenoid valve* which lets gas in, back to the thermocouple.